# Backwards Compatibility of Google APIS in Android

Tags: android, google-api, build-target

I am trying to import sample code with

**Build target: Google APIS 1.6**

**minSDK: 4**

I have downloaded the Android API 4 but the lowest Google APIS version I find on the SDK Manager is 8.

Eclipse creates a blank project with no classes and throws `AndroidManifest.xml file missing!`

Theres a few things I dont understand:

When I create a project using Google APIS only the Google APIS version is important? I forget about Android API?

Are Google APIS versions backwards compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Google API SDK should be available from 1.6 and up version.
They contain the basic SDK for the version, and additional APIs such as C2DM.
Not sure what you mean with backwards compatbility. An 2.2 version SDK should be able to use 1.6. API calls.

Comment: _An 2.2 version SDK should be able to use 1.6. API calls._  @Thxdemonick, that's what I meant. But still 2.2 is the lowest I can see. So I shoud be able to run the project with a Build target: Google APIS 15 ??  Besides, I still dont understand why it doesnt import the AndroidManifest.xml